# Is it possible to know executive (.exe) compilation date from linked static library (.lib)

Tags: c++, windows, static-libraries, static-linking

I am developing a commercial static library and wondering if it is possible to find out the date when the .exe that uses it was compiled, or some other similar information.

In case this is my .exe file, I would use the `__DATE__` macro, but as far as I know, macros are expanded during preprocessing, which is already done when I have a .lib file, thus I will have the date my .lib was compiled, instead of .exe.

Is where any other way?
Is it even possible?

Comment: if you provide entry point for you library, you might require `__DATE__` there...

Comment: Some executable file formats include a build date, but not all do.   Even if they do, not all linkers populate that field and there are programs that strip such data out. The only portable way would be for (1)  the library provide a function that accepts a date in some form (e.g. a string) as an argument AND (2)  every executable call that function, with an argument based on `__DATE__` in `main()` during startup.  Your library would need to cope with the fact that some executables may omit that information (e.g. because the programmer forgot to call the function).

Comment: The exact datetime the .exe file was created is available in the [.exe header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_file_header), TimeDateStamp field.  Probably just easier to retrieve the file creation date.  GetModuleFileName(NULL, ...) retrieves the path to the .exe

Comment: @han That's what the `TimeDateStamp` was initially intended to be used for. Apart from being subject to the [Y2k38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) problem, clients have started using it for something else entirely (see [Why are the module timestamps in Windows 10 so nonsensical?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180103-00/?p=97705), for example).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Hans Passant for showing me where to look. Here's a quick solution I made based on his comment:

```
DWORD datePEbuilt = 0;
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* DosHeader = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*) GetModuleHandle(NULL);
if (DosHeader->e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
{
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* peHeader = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)((u_char*)DosHeader + DosHeader->e_lfanew);
    if (peHeader->Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    {
        datePEbuilt = peHeader->FileHeader.TimeDateStamp;
    }
}
```

Requires some cleanup and error check, but it works with both x86 and x64 builds!